# Symfony Fileupload in AWS

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting started with Symfony and AWS. I'm developing an application where the user can upload a profile picture and create an image gallery. So far, locally I've managed to do that and save the images in a directory (/web/img). Now I want to move this app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The instance and RDS are created and the app is runing, but I want to know the correct form to upload files, so in every deploy I don't lose the user images.

I've read some articles about S3 using some Symfony Libraries, but everything still looks a bit fuzzy to understand and put it together.

How can I set a S3 to work together with my Elastic Bean Instance?
How can I upload content to the S3 environment using Symfony?
And how I'm gonna serve the uploaded content?

Can someone help me in this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application will have to be changed to upload the users' images to an S3 bucket instead of to the local file system. Take some time to familiarize yourself with how files are stored in S3 and general [S3 concepts](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/). (S3 has buckets, buckets have objects, objects are files.)

There are PHP samples for S3 available on the [AWS S3 PHP SDK page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html). You can include the AWS SDK in Symfony through the [aws-sdk-php-symfony](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-symfony) project.

Once you get more comfortable with S3 and the terminology, you will likely want to look at using [pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-presigned-url.html) for object uploads.

You can serve the files using pre-signed URLs also (if applicable to your requirements), or you can use the AWS SDK to retrieve the images directly.

Comment: Thank you jbird, I'll look through these docs you recommended. AWS is totally new to me.

Comment: Got it! Thank you @jbird, folowing your instructions I've managed to upload an image and store its name in RDS.